# How to find the source of failure in fail() method of BaseRichSpout - Apache Storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a topology as follows:

```
Spout --> Bolt 1 --> Bolt2 --> Bolt3
```

Where Spout has a stream `"mystream"` that is subscribed by **Bolt2** and other stream `"bolt1stream"` is where **Bolt1** receives tuples.

In case of failure of tuples(Bolt2 in my case), I would like to **replay it from Bolt2 not again from Bolt1**

For this, I'll fail the tuple in Bolt2. When this fail message reaches spout, I emit it to mystream / bolt1stream based on the point where it failed. So it would start processing from the fail point.

However the fail() in `BaseRichSpout` has Object parameter, instead of Tuple. How would I know the `sourceComponent`, as I would do with Tuple? Or what is the best way to replay a tuple from wherever it failed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For each stream, I use a separate class to identify the stream. The alternative is to use the same class and have an integer or enum inside the class which identifies the stream.

```
@Override
public void fail(Object msgId) {
   if (msgId instanceof MyTupleClass) {
   // Default stream   
   MyTupleClass oneTuple = (MyTupleClass) msgId;
   //---tuple replay logic. Re-emitting the failed tuples    
   ReEmitTheDefaultStreamTuple(oneTuple);
}
else {
   //it's the other stream
   //For this stream you could perhaps use MySecondTupleClass
}
```

Comment: MyTupleClass is just a class you create to store the data you want to send to the bolt. Implement it however you like: `class MyTupleClass { public String someInfo;}`. Additionally, if you would like to have extended discussions on problems, there is the storm mailing list http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/. If this answer of mine was helpful, you could upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: can I also ack(MyTupleClass) ? I get an error saying `org.quadrisk.utils.EventTuple cannot be converted to backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple`